# What to read to understand how Java works?

Tags: java

Knowing how Java works in initializing objects and how it bind methods and fields to an object , abstract , final methods to an object and some other issues take a lot of time to guess myself , and i needed to ensure that every guess i made was correct by asking here and there .
I need some recommendations to read or watch (books-tutorials-articles-videos) , thanks in advance

Comment: Read a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75102/best-java-book-you-have-read-so-far) on Java. I recommed Thinking in Java by Bruce Eckel.

Comment: hhh , this is the book i am reading right now , which made me wanna know about java internals !

Comment: @Prasoon, I get the impression the OP is actually past that (beginner) point and is interested in understanding how Java works under the hood.

Answer (score 8):

What better source than Sun's [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/)?

Comment: Personally I'd recommend the VM spec to truly understand what's going on under the hood -- how Java works.  http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/VMSpecTOC.doc.html

Comment: May I also suggest reading the GPL'ed source code for OpenJDK, javac compiler and HotSpot VM? http://openjdk.java.net/ http://openjdk.java.net/groups/compiler/ http://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/

Comment: The Java Language Specification is a terrible introduction text, it's for people who build compilers and need an exact syntax description!

Comment: Yes, and please write us when you read it:-) <- do not go for that.

Comment: who said he was looking for an introductory text? he's looking for under-the-hood insights and reading specs and reference implementations are the best source.

Answer (score 2):

You can read any java book out there, there is a ton. But you won't know how java works until you actually start programming. Find a project and start coding!

I do like the Head First series for beginners. There is a Java book they publish. http://headfirstlabs.com/

Comment: +1 For the advice to actually PROGRAM SOMETHING!

Comment: that is true , but i am concentrating now on understanding deeply , i realized that i need to understand how it works first !

Answer (score 1):

Go through the article in http://www.javaworld.com/ and such sites.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to understand how java works i would recommend [Inside Java Virtual Machine](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071350934) by Bill Veeners

Answer (score 0):

If you want low-level knowledge, perhaps studying the JVM itself would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Effective Java by Joshua Block http://astore.amazon.com/techncafe-20/detail/0321356683

Java Concurrency in Practice by Brian Goetz  http://astore.amazon.com/techncafe-20/detail/0321349601

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently waiting for [Beginning Java Objects: From Concepts to Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1861004176) to arrive on my doorstep. I hope it will be what you are looking for. I am purchasing this book because I too need help understanding objects in the Java language. I think it would be best to understand how objects are used in the language, then continue studying the language itself.

After that book, I'll go onto (or read at the same time) Beginning Java 2 by Ivor Horton. Both books received really good reviews on Amazon, so hopefully they are good for both you and I.

Answer (score 0):

What I think you are getting at is how java really works under the hood. To that end, I think you would do well to understand byte-code, what java is interpreted to, and what the byte-code instructions mean to the jvm. By understanding what all of the Java language features convert to on a more raw level, you'll walk away with a much deeper understanding that, honestly, few people I've met have on the subject.

To this end, I'm going to suggest something that is a bit of a deviation from the norm and tell you to look at this book, [Expert .NET 2.0 IL Assembler](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590596463) . That book is on the .NET intermediate language, the analogue to java's byte-code. I'm suggesting that simply because no good book exists on this for Java byte-code, and this is book gave me the understanding to easily tackle Java.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go back to basics and read a good Java introduction (just skip the parts you know), as these are realy basic Java questions you have. Most popular text is:

**[Head First Java (2nd edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596009208)**

Or for a more down to earth advanced text:

**[Core Java, Volume I - Fundementals (8th edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132354764)**

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend SCJP preparation book:
''SCJP Sun Certified Programmer for Java 6 Study Guide''.
It has good overview over all java components. It speaks about neat areas, that you might get surprised with.